# Uncaught Runtime Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). Why is the data received from React-Query undefined?

Tags: reactjs, tanstackreact-query

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const Query = () => {
    const { data:userData } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["user"], queryFn: async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                const data = await res.json()
                return data;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
        // return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((res) => res.json())
    })

    return (
        <div>
            {userData.map((user) => {
                return <p>{user.name}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Query
```

As far as I am aware, the queryFn inside the useQuery hook by react-query, should return the data fetched by the Fetch function. And react-query will then store the data in the variable userData, which can be displayed on the screen. But why in this case it is saying userData is undefined? Am I missing something here? Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: This hook is asynchronous so the default value of `data` is `undefined`. `useQuery` also return an `isLoading` boolean that you can use to conditionally render the list. Also please use the HTML tag [`ul`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) to display a list.

Comment: Check a complete example there: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/guides/queries